# Зачем нужно использовать mock объекты?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты, moq

Говорится что эта технология позволяет имитировать объект. Зачем это надо если этот объект можно просто создать?

Comment: Для юнит тестирования.

Comment: не все объекты можно _просто_ создать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мок объект позволяет:

Отделить логику тестируемого класса от логики интерфейсов от которых он зависит. Представь ситуацию что в зависимости от поведения класса B меняется поведение класса A. Так как в тесте ты можешь добится любого поведения мок объекта - mock< IB>, ты можешь протестировать свой класс таким образом как посчитаешь нужным.

```
class A {
  IB _b;

  public A (IB b){
    _b = b;
  }

  public string foo(str){
    return _b.bar(str);
  }
}
```

Позволяет упростить создание тестируемого обьекта. Так в тесте не придётся создавать все зависимости класса B и все те зависимости от которых зависим он.

```
class A {
    public A (IB b)
}

class B {
    public B (IC b, ID d, IE e  ... )
}
```

Он позволяет избавится от возможных длительных операций (к примеру с вводом-выводом).

```
class A {
    public A (IB b)
}

interface IB {
    string SomeLongIO(string str);
}
```